# connect to voip gateway and wifi for internet on same windows machine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, voip

I have a situation which i will try to explain:

i have subscribed for a SIP line. In my country, it is delivered via a MUX device and a cat6 cable. I have connected that to my soft PBX which is installed in my windows 10 machine via ethernet.

However, that SIP line does not have internet. So to connect to internet, i need to use my office wifi.

The issue is, the SIP server pings only if default gateway is of mux device. If i set that as default gateway, then internet does not connect.

Looking for possible solutions. Thanks in advance. 
- Singh

Comment: Please note i need an internet connection on my pbx machine for notifications from pbx server.

Comment: That's a slightly complicated situation, you should add more details e.g. regarding the SIP server, the MUX the PBX, specifying which equipment is yours and which is the provider's...don't post comments, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1358164/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you are in two networks and each network has its own default gateway, the best solution is to create an static route to the VoIP Server.

If you open **CMD** and type `route print` you will se something like this:

[image]

It is the list of routes that your PC knows.

You can issue the command:

`route ADD destination_network MASK subnet_mask  gateway_ip metric_cost` to add an static route that forces your VoIP traffic to go to the MUX while the other traffic goes to the wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

Being connected to multiple networks simultaneously can problematic for most end nodes, especially for end users that don’t understand how IP routing works. To prevent issues, most mobile devices have a priority order for interfaces and disable all bit the most attractive, active one.
Even if you activated both interfaces simultaneously, only one would provide a “default route” out to the Internet, so only one would be functionally active anyway. To conduct any form of load balancing would require manual route management and an understanding about the implications for the return traffic.

Source: [Why can’t I use my Wi-Fi and USB tethering at the same time? Whenever I turn my USB tethering option on, it switches off automatically and resets USB tethering to charging only.](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-I-use-my-Wi-Fi-and-USB-tethering-at-the-same-time-Whenever-I-turn-my-USB-tethering-option-on-it-switches-off-automatically-and-resets-USB-tethering-to-charging-only)

Such a network is very unstable and it is not recommended to set up our network because the system automatically creates a default route when the network is reconnected. However, we can try to set it as below:

For example, we can set the ethernet setting as below:

local IP address: 192.168.1.2

subnet mask:255.255.255.0

gateway:192.168.1.1

And the wifi setting as below:

local IP address: 192.168.42.2

subnet mask:255.255.255.0

gateway:192.168.42.1

We can set network discard as usual, now there are two gateways pointing to "0.0.0.0", so we need to configure the routing table.

1. Open command prompt, run as administrator.
2. Type "route print ", click "Enter".

[image]

3. Type"route delete 0.0.0.0" (delete all the routing table of "0.0.0.0" ), click "Enter".
4. Type "route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1" ("-p" means permanent or static, it prevents configuration from disappearing on next reboot), click "Enter".

   **-->Add an static route to force VoIP traffic to go to the MUX.**
5. Type "route -p add 192.168.42.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.42.1", click "Enter".

   **-->The other traffic goes to the wifi network.**